# help me point out errors

Tags: mathbb

This is my entire latex program:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%------------------------------------->% permet d'écrire  directement avec les absents
\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}%---------------------------------->% code les règle typogragiques françaises
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}%-------------------------------->% codage du fichier source
%\usepackage{latexsym}%---------------------------------------->% des symboles courants
\usepackage{pdfpages}%---------------------------------------->% permet d inclure des fichiers entiers pdf
\usepackage{xspace}%------------------------------------------>% pour ne pas taper les accolades à la fin de certaines commandes si lonveut un espace derrière ex 1\ier exercice au lieu d e 1\ier{}
\usepackage{amscd}%------------------------------------------->% permet la construction de diagrammes commutatifs voir latex-bemaer-p74
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb,amsmath,eufrak,amsfonts}%--------->% permet de produire des formules et symboles mathematiques compliquées
\usepackage{graphicx}%---------------------------------------->% importer des figure dans le document
\usepackage{dsfont}%------------------------------------------>% permet d'utiliser mathds
\usepackage{lettrine}%---------------------------------------->% permmet deproduire lettrine \lettrine{Elle} ou \lettrine{E}lle
\usepackage[french2]{minitoc}%-------------------------------->% permet d'avoir des mini-tables de matière en français "sommaire"
\usepackage{xcolor,rotating,epic,eepic}%---------------------->% couleurs, rotation d'un texte
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}%--------------------------------------->% permet de déssiner directement dans le fichié source
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through,backgrounds}
\usepgflibrary{decorations.footprints}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.footprints}
\usepackage{fancybox}%---------------------------------------->% fancybox permet de produire cadre ombre noire
\usepackage{enumerate}%--------------------------------------->% un joli package qui améliore l'environnement enumerate du au celèbre "David Car-lisle"
\usepackage{expdlist}%---------------------------------------->% permet d'insérer un paragraphe dans une liste sans en boulverser la numérotation
\usepackage{array}%------------------------------------------->% pour produire des paragraphe centré dans un tableau
\usepackage{delarray}%---------------------------------------->% package qui améliore l'environnement array (facilite les choses)
\usepackage{tabularx}%---------------------------------------->% pour tableau X
\usepackage{wrapfig}%----------------------------------------->% Pour mettre du texte autour dune figure
\usepackage{pbsi,aurical,calligra}%--------------------->% fonte
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%---------------------------------------->% pour \mathscr
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amscd}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%
%%
%%=================================================================================================================
%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~GÉOMÉTRIE DE LA FUEILLE~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%%=================================================================================================================
%%
%%
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{geometry}%|--------------------------------------->% difini les differentes dimention de chaque page
\geometry{%
left=2.5cm,right =2.5cm,  %|---------------------------------->% fixe les marges à gauche et à droite
top =2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,   %|--------------------------------->% fixe les marges en haut et en bas
marginparwidth=1.2cm, marginparsep=3mm %---------------------->% indique la largeur des notes marginales
 }
\linespread{1.4}%--------------------------------------------->% l'interligne
%%
%%
%==================================================================================================================
%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ENTÊTE ET PIED DE PAGE~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%==================================================================================================================
%%
%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%---------------------------------------->% pour l'entête et pied de page
\pagestyle{fancy} %%% Left Even, Right Odd
%=================================================  EN-TÊTE : =====================================================
%%
\fancyhf{}%--------------------------------------------------->% supprime les en-têtes et pieds predefines
%\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\bfseries\leftmark}}%-------------->% [Left]=[gauche] écrire en minuscule et en gras le nom du chapitre courant
%\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\bfseries\rightmark}}%------------->% [Right]=[droite] écrire en minuscule et en gras la section courante
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}%--------------------------->% un trait en haut de page d'épaiceur 2 points
%%
%================================================  PIED DE PAGE : =================================================
%%
\fancyfoot[L]{%
\footnotesize{\textbf{Masters Dissertation }}}%-------------->% pied de page à gauche
\fancyfoot[R]{%
\footnotesize{{\bsc{ BOGNY KENFACK Bob J. \copyright~ UY1 2017}}}}%------->% idem
\fancyfoot[c]{%
\fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\color{white}\textbf{\thepage}}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}%--------------------------->% épaisseur des traits
%%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %------------------------------------->% pages de tetes de chapitre
\fancyhead{}            %------------------------------------->% supprime l'entete
\fancyfoot{}            %------------------------------------->% supprime le pied de page
\fancyfoot[L]{%
\footnotesize{\textbf{Masters Dissertation }}}%-------------->% pied de page à gauche
\fancyfoot[R]{%
\footnotesize{{\bsc{BOGNY KENFACK Bob J. \copyright~ UY1 2017}}}}}%------->% idem
\fancyfoot[c]{%
\fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\color{white}\textbf{\emph{\thepage}}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % et le filet
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancypagestyle{myheadings}{\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries Introduction}%
\fancyfoot[L]{%
\footnotesize{\textbf{Masters Dissertation }}}%-------------->% pied de page à gauche
\fancyfoot[R]{%
\footnotesize{{\bsc{ BOGNY KENFACK Bob J. \copyright~ UY1 2017}}}}}%------->% idem
\fancyfoot[c]{%
\fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\color{white}\textbf{\thepage}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
%%
%==================================================================================================================%
%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~NEWTHEOREME~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
%==================================================================================================================%
%%
%%
\newtheorem{propriete}{\textbf{Properties}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{\textbf{Definition}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemme}{\textbf{Lemma}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}{\textbf{Proposition}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollaire}{\textbf{Corollary}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theoreme}{\fcolorbox{gray!50}{gray!50}{\color{black}\textbf{Theorem}}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{assumption}{\textbf{Assumption}}[chapter]
\newtheorem{thmetdefn}{Theorem and Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{rappel}{Recall}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{definition}%------------------------------------>% permet de ne pas écrire le contenu de ce qui suit en italique
\newtheorem{example}{\textbf{\underline{Example}}}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{\textbf{\underline{Notation}}}[section]
\newtheorem{note}{\textbf{\underline{Note}}}[section]
\newtheorem{remarque}{\textbf{Remark}}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}{\underline{Exercise}}[section]
%%
%%


%==================================================================================================================%
%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~PART FRAME~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
%==================================================================================================================%
%%
%%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thepartwords}
{ \ifcase \thepart\or  Un \or Deux\or Trois\or Quatre\or Cinq\or
  Six\or Sept\or Huit\or Neuf\or Dix\or Onze\fi}
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{15\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \hrule
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\color{white}\textbf{ \@chapapp{} \thechapterwords}}
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \quad \hrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
        \hrule
        \par
        \vspace*{8\p@}%
        \thickhrulefill\quad
    \vskip 60\p@
    %\vskip 100\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{15\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \hrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
        \Large{$\clubsuit$}
        \hspace{0.3cm}
        \Huge \bfseries #1 \hspace{0.3cm}\Large{$\clubsuit$}\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
        \hrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrulefill
    \vskip 60\p@
    %\vskip 100\p@
  }}
  \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{15\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \hrule
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        $\star~~\star$\hspace{0.3cm}\fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\color{white}\textbf{ \@chapapp{}\thechapterwords}}
        \hspace{0.3cm}$\star~~\star$
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \quad \hrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
        \hrule
        \par
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrulefill
        \par
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \hrule
    \vskip 60\p@
    %\vskip 100\p@
  }}
%%
%%
%==================================================================================================================%
%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~CHAPTER FRAME~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
%==================================================================================================================%
%%
%%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thechapterwords}
{ \ifcase \thechapter\or  One \or Two\or Three\or Four\or Five\or
  Six\or Seven\or Eight\or Nine\or Ten\or eleven\fi}
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{15\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \hrule
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\color{white}\textbf{ \@chapapp{} \thechapterwords}}
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \quad \hrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
        \hrule
        \par
        \vspace*{8\p@}%
        \thickhrulefill\quad
    \vskip 60\p@
    %\vskip 100\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{15\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \hrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
        \Large{$\clubsuit$}
        \hspace{0.3cm}
        \Huge \bfseries #1 \hspace{0.3cm}\Large{$\clubsuit$}\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
        \hrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrulefill
    \vskip 60\p@
    %\vskip 100\p@
  }}
  \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{15\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \hrule
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        $\star~~\star$\hspace{0.3cm}\fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\color{white}\textbf{ \@chapapp{}\thechapterwords}}
        \hspace{0.3cm}$\star~~\star$
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \quad \hrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
        \hrule
        \par
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrulefill
        \par
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \hrule
    \vskip 60\p@
    %\vskip 100\p@
  }}
%%
%%
%==================================================================================================================%
%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*~~~~COMMANDES~~~~~*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
%==================================================================================================================%
%%
%%
%
\newcommand{\fonction}[5]{%
\begin{array}{clcl}
 #1 : & #2  & \longrightarrow & #3\\
       & #4  & \longmapsto     & #5
  \end{array}
}
\newcommand{\fonctionb}[5]{%
\begin{array}[b]{clcl}
  #1 : & #2  & \longrightarrow & #3\\
       & #4  & \longmapsto     & #5
  \end{array}
}
%
\newcommand{\g}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\T}[1]{\text{#1}}
\newcommand{\reel}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\gm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
\newcommand{\psum}[3]{\overset{#1}{\underset{#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\fn}[1]{\footnotesize{#1}}
\newcommand{\bb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\Ro}{\mathcal{R}}
%\newcommand{\cal}[1]{\mathcal{#1}} %existe dèjà
%\newcommand{\frak}[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}%existe dèjà
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\croh}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\pa}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\ens}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\da}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\Da}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\lda}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lda}{\Longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ga}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\lga}{\longleftarrow}
\newcommand{\Lga}{\Longleftarrow}
\newcommand{\gda}{\leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Gda}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\lgda}{\longleftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lgda}{\iff}
\def\Oij{$\left(\text{O},~\vec{\imath},~\vec{\jmath}\right)\text{ }$}
\def\Oijk{$\left(\text{O},~\vec{\imath},~ \vec{\jmath},~ \vec{k}\right)\text{ }$}
\def\ijk{$\left(\vec{\imath},~ \vec{\jmath},~ \vec{k}\right)\text{ }$}
\def\ij{$\left(\vec{\imath},~ \vec{\jmath}\right)\text{ }$}
\def\Ouv{$\left(\text{O},~\vec{u},~\vec{v}\right)\text{ }$}
\def\uv{$\left(\vec{u},~\vec{v}\right)\text{ }$}
\newcommand{\Monge}{\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]%Mon ge
\draw[ball color=green] (-.6,-.9)rectangle (1.9,.85); \draw[ultra
thick,blue](.5,.5)..controls
(.58,.56)and(.85,.56)..(.9,.5)--(.91,.4); \draw[ultra
thick,red](.1,0)--(.1,.5)--(.3,.3)--(.5,.5)--(.5,0); \draw[ultra
thick,blue] (.5,0) .. controls (.58,-.06)and
(.85,-.06)..(.9,0)..controls (1,.03)..(1.1,0);\draw[ultra thick]
(.87,.2) .. controls (.9,.1)..(.9,0)..
controls(.87,-.15)..(.9,-.2)..controls (1,-.18)..(1.1,-.2);
\draw[ultra thick](.68,.23).. controls
(.8,.18)..(.9,.2)..controls(1,.23)..(1.1,.2); \draw[ultra
thick](0,.1)..controls
(-.2,-.33)and(-0.1,-.4)..(.1,-.4)..controls(1,-.3)..(1.6,-.46);
\draw[ultra
thick](0,.1)..controls(-.24,-.3)and(-.4,-.65)..(0,-.56)..controls(.9,-.4)..(1.6,-.46);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}}
%%
%==================================================================================================================%
%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*~~deux environnement pour la preuve (proof et preuve)~~*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
%==================================================================================================================%
%%
\addto\captionsfrench{%
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\bfseries \underline{Proof}}
}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{0.6em}{0.6em}}
%
\newenvironment{preuve}[1][\underline{Proof}]
{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.6em}{0.6em}}
%
%
\thispagestyle{empty}%----------------------------------------->% pour obtenir une premiere page sans entête ni pied de page
%

%
\title{ \textbf{{\LARGE {ARBITRAGE AND COMPLETNESS IN FINANCIAL MARKET MODELS}}}\\
    Dissertation submitted in partial fulfillement of the requirements for the award of a \\
    \textbf{Masters of Science in Mathematics}\\
    Option : Dynamic Systems and Modelling\\
    By\\
    \textbf{BOGNY KENFACK Bob James}\\
    Matricule : $12V0820$\\
    Under the supervision of \\
        \textbf{Pr.AYISSI Raoul} \\
        Associate professor (U.Y.1)\\
    \textbf{Dr. MBELE BIDIMA Martin Le Doux} \\
    Senior Lecturer (U.Y.1)\\
    \date{Academic year 2016/2017}
    \author{}} %%
%%
%==================================================================================================================%
%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*~ début du document ~*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
%==================================================================================================================%
%%
%%{\color{blue} \dingline{45}}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I am unable to reproduce the message you report getting if I make your code compilable by (a) changing `\usepackage{Lettrine}` to `\usepackage{lettrine}`and (b) adding the instructions `\begin{document} \subsection{$L^p$ Spaces} \end{document}`. Please provide code that is (a) compilable and (b) generates the issue you wish to fix.

Comment: Aside: Do you really need to load all these packages? For sure, there can be no valid reason for loading `latexsym`: it's a package that has been deprecated since ca 1994 and has been superseded by `amssymb`. It would probably be a good idea for you to go through the preamble and decide which packages you really need and which ones you shouldn't be loading.

Comment: do you _really_ use all those packages (I have not seen many  documents use eepic this century)  here you are using the bbold package but don't appear to have the fonts installed. It is best to only load packages that you are actually using.

Comment: There's definitely something odd going on in your document: It's trying to typeset `L^p` in the sectioning header in blackboard-bold (aka double-struck) math mode instead of regular math mode. There must be some instructions in your document that attempt to change "regular" math to "blackboard-bold" math. Do please tell us more.

Comment: It seems you're using Windows, possibly MiKTeX. Is this it?

Comment: You should use the `utf8` input encoding. Most modern editors encode by default in utf8. Also the language options of `babel`, since version 3.9, should be loaded with the document class. The standard package for commutative diagrams is `tikz-cd` nowadays.

Comment: The code as posted now runs without error (and makes no output) as such it is hard to know what help you want?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: There's no question at all here: just some code which is expected to output nothing. No error. No undesirable output. Nothing at all. I don't know what error @Mico is referring to?

Comment: @Bernard TeXShop doesn't.

Comment: @cfr - The initial, by now overwritten, version of the query's title contained an error message that was baffling the OP. That's what I was referring to. I agree that with the new/improved title, my comment doesn't make sense any longer.

Comment: @cfr: I know, and it's quite unfortunate. It leads to problems when copying tex files on other systems.